# How to assign a groovy variable to a shell variable, getting error in Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

How to assign a groovy variable to a shell variable , getting error in Jenkins Pipeline

```
pipeline {
agent any
stages {
    stage ('test') {
        steps {
            script {
                sh """
                    def count = sh(script: "cat changes.txt | wc -l", returnStdout: true)
                    echo "Var is " + count
                    if (count == 1) {
                        env.INFO1=(REL-${BUILD_NUMBER})
                        echo "INFO1" + INFO1   
                    } else {
                        env.INFO1= 'condition not success'
                        echo "INFO1" + INFO1
                    }
                   """ }}}}}
```

> Error: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Comment: can you please add your post block also

Comment: Tested with small program , but there is no luck 
pipeline {    stages {  stage ('test') { steps { script {
                    sh """
                       echo "1" > changes.txt
                       count=\$(cat changes.txt | wc -l)
                       echo \$count
                       if [ \$count = 0 ]; then
                            info='condition success'
    echo \$info
                      else
                            info=(REL-${BUILD_NUMBER})
   echo \$info
                     fi
                       """
sh "echo ${info}"  \\ no output }}}}

Comment: can you remove the space between stage and open brace. eg: stage('test')

Comment: Tried but getting same response. When I use different sh block code it is not throwing any error.

Comment: `def count = sh(script: "cat changes.txt | wc -l", returnStdout: true)` inside `sh` doesn't make any sense. Open a `bash` window and try to run it.

Comment: based on below suggestion , i executed the same . Could you please help me with some example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the "sh" block with the below code:-

```
def count = sh(script: "cat changes.txt | wc -l", returnStdout: true)
echo "Var is " + count
if (count == 1) {
         env.INFO1=(REL-${BUILD_NUMBER})
         echo "INFO1" + INFO1   
    } else {
         env.INFO1= 'condition not success'
         echo "INFO1" + INFO1
}
```

Comment: getting error : line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `(' , same as posted above , tried but no luck ..

Comment: add the block which I have posted and remove the sh block from your code

Comment: can you please rate the answer also, Thank You!